# the column that i have added in excel have only one value for all rows

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, openpyxl

i'm adding a column in an excel sheet and the values don't seem right

```
ws["J1"] = "Stars"
ws["J1"].font = Font(bold=True, name='Arial', size=10)
stars =[2,2,4,5,3,5,4,2,3,4,5,2,3,5,4,5,1,4,2,3,2,2,4,5,3,5,3,5,4,5,2,3,5,4,5,4,2,3,3,5,4,5,2,3,5,4,5,4,2,3]
for i in range(2,67):
    for j in range(len(stars)):
        ws.cell(row=i, column=10).value = stars[j]
```

but then the column has only the nomber 3

Comment: Your inner loop is overwriting the cell until it gets to the last element of the list. Your list has less elements than cells you are trying to write to, so not sure what your end goal is supposed to look like.

Comment: If you just want to insert values into column J you can just loop over stars directly.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever possible, avoid creating your own counters.

```py
for idx, star in enumerate(stars, start=2):
   ws.cell(column=10, row=idx, value=star)
```

Comment: it doesn't read all the list

Comment: Please provide more information.

Answer (score -3):

this cause your are rewriting the same cell and 3 is the last number in your array .
Try like this:

```
ws["J1"] = "Stars"
ws["J1"].font = Font(bold=True, name='Arial', size=10)
stars =[2,2,4,5,3,5,4,2,3,4,5,2,3,5,4,5,1,4,2,3,2,2,4,5,3,5,3,5,4,5,2,3,5,4,5,4,2,3,3,5,4,5,2,3,5,4,5,4,2,3]
for i in range(2,67):
    for j in range(len(stars)):
        ws.cell(row=i, column=10).value = stars[j]
    next j
next i
```

Comment: This is the same code as the op with some added in syntax errors.

Comment: @cco it gives me the following error Exception has occurred: TypeError
'int' object is not an iterator